Getting an TypeError for a serborn code for visualisation
Getting this error:

TypeError: 'Axes' object is not subscriptable

this is the code :
fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(job_titles), 1)

sns.set_theme(style='ticks')

for i, job_title in enumerate(job_titles):
    df_plot = df_skills_count[df_skills_count['job_title_short'] == job_title].head(5)[::-1]
    sns.barplot(data=df_plot, x='skill_count', y='job_skills', ax=ax[i], hue='skill_count', palette='dark:b_r')
    ax[i].set_title(job_title)
    ax[i].invert_yaxis()
    ax[i].set_ylabel('')
    ax[i].set_xlabel('')
    ax[i].get_legend().remove()
    ax[i].set_xlim(0, 45000) # make the scales the same

fig.suptitle('Counts of Skills Requested in US Job Postings', fontsize=15)
fig.tight_layout(h_pad=0.5) # fix the overlap
plt.show()

This is the whole error I'm getting:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent
Cell In[44], line 7
      5 for i, job_title in enumerate(job_titles):
      6     df_plot = df_skills_count[df_skills_count['job_title_short'] == job_title].head(5)[::-1]
----> 7     sns.barplot(data=df_plot, x='skill_count', y='job_skills', ax=ax[i], hue='skill_count', palette='dark:b_r')
      8     ax[i].set_title(job_title)
      9     ax[i].invert_yaxis()

TypeError: 'Axes' object is not subscriptable

can someone suggest how can i fix this error or what if wrong in this error?
enter image description here
I am trying to get this plot.

Your code is missing reproducible test data. When len(job_titles) would be 1, ax won't be an array, but just a single ax.   Also note that it is recommended to avoid indices. It would be better to use zip() instead of enumerate().   E.g.  fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(job_titles), 1) and then for ax, job_title in zip(np.array(axs), job_titles):.  (Here np.array(axs) is a trick to make it work both with a single and multiples axes).

Thanks brother for your answer will sure try this code and see if it works.

when added this line: for ax, job_title in zip(np.array(ax), job_titles):  i am still getting this error:   'Axes' object is not subscriptable after i changed the axs to ax in the for loop, but this time i am getting 3 subplots but not plotting the things that i want to , so any suggestions?

You need to replace ax[i] by simply ax when using for ax, job_title in zip(np.array(axs), job_titles):.  (Note that axs is used inside the zip). If you get 3 subplots, then maybe you now have 3 job_titles? Note that it would help of lot if you'd add reproducible test data to your post. (Your original error would only be there in case you'd only have 1 job_title, but maybe you are using the same code for multiple datasets).
